# What causes the car in the Vehicle Advanced template to rotate in the air?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

If you start a project with the Vehicle Advanced template, move the car high up, and press play, the car will rotate forwards as it falls. As far as I can tell, most things within Unreal Engine will maintain a given orientation as they fall. This is true for car in the regular Vehicle template, as well.

What causes Vehicle Advanced to behave this way? And is there a way to stop this behavior?

Comment: Center of mass ?

Comment: I don't think that's it. If you take any other actor, like a regular cube, and move it's center of mass to some random position, you can see that the cube will still land flatly on its face (or maintain any other orientation it was in before hitting the ground). Of course, upon hitting the ground, the way it'll behave will be different, but I'm fairly certain the location of the CoM does not affect an actor's orientation as it falls.